# How can i know which chef dk version includes chef-client version 11.18.12?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I want to install chef-dk in my workstation with specific chef-client version 11.18.12 included. But i wasn't able to find which chef-dk version has the required chef-client version in it. please help me.

Comment: Still need a table of version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

ChefDK was released concurrently with Chef 12 if I remember correctly, I don't think it has ever been packaged with Chef 11.x.